# Is it possible to copy a searched string from one file and print into another?

Tags: c

The following function is only used to display certain areas of a file. In this case I am trying to copy every line that has the word "EMPTY" from the main file to another file. Other than by opening a file to write to I use for char arrays to look for the proper string needed. At this point, I try to use the data from that file(In which the string was searched for) and try to copy it into another file. At this point some of the new file prints to the screen which is the first part at the top under where I created the file but when I try to add the string from the other file they do no print. Can you print certain string fro one file to another?

```
void emptySeats(void)
    {
        int position = 0;
        int AvalabileOne = 0;
        int countGone = 0;
        int confirm = 0; 
        char testOne[] = "EMPTY";
        char StrOne[10], StrTwo[10], StrThree[10], StrFour[10];

        FILE *fEmptyseatArrangement;
        fEmptyseatArrangement = fopen("airlineEmptySeatingArrangment.txt", "w+");
        fprintf(fseatArrangement, "\t\t\tEcono-Airlines Passangers System\n\n\t   Seat Number\t Seatavalability      Last Name      First Name\n");

        do
        {
            fseatArrangement = fopen("airlineSeatingArrangment.txt", "r");
            fseek(fseatArrangement, 102, SEEK_SET);


            while (AvalabileOne < FULL)
            {
                fscanf(fseatArrangement, "%s%s%s%s\n", &StrOne, &StrTwo, &StrThree, &StrFour);
                if (strcmp(StrThree, testOne))
                {
                    fprintf(fEmptyseatArrangement, "\t\t%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\n", StrOne, StrTwo, StrThree, StrFour);
                    countGone = countGone + 1;
                }
                AvalabileOne = AvalabileOne + 1;
            }
            fclose(fEmptyseatArrangement);
            fclose(fseatArrangement);

            fEmptyseatArrangement = fopen("airlineEmptySeatingArrangment.txt", "r");
            while (fgets(econoAirEmptySeatArrangement, 1000, fEmptyseatArrangement) != NULL)
                printf("%s", econoAirEmptySeatArrangement);
            fclose(fEmptyseatArrangement);
            printf("There are %d seats vacant at the moment\n", FULL - countGone);


            printf("Enter Zero(0) Key to return to menu at anytime.");
            scanf(" %d", &position);
            if (position == 0)
            {
                system("cls");
                menu();
            }
            else
            {
                system("cls");
                printf("INVALID INPUT! Please try again.\n");
            }
        } while (AvalabileOne != 0);

        system("pause");
        return;
    }
```

Comment: It's possible you have misunderstood what `strcmp` returns.